# Pulling data from one or another column for an average, based on NULL of one column

Tags: sql-server

I've searched for a while on how to do this but I've barely been using SQL Dev a week so I might be missing something obvious.

I'm trying to query an average value based on two columns. I can get averages for each column individually but I'm having trouble going further. Here's the table format:

```
Value  Override  ID  Hourend
19     (Null)    1   6:00
23     (Null)    1   4:00
45     18        1   6:00
66     (Null)    2   6:00
68     (Null)    2   5:00
72     (Null)    1   5:00
81     45        1   5:00
```

What I'm wanting is an average of the Value column per hour, by ID. That I've done using:

```
SELECT AVG (Value)
  (OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Hourend) as Average
FROM Database.Table;
```

However, I also need to have an average with Override substituting Value of the same row when not Null. So basically I need a way to pull Override instead of Value when Override isn't Null.

I've fiddled with CASE statements and other tools with no success as of yet. Efficiency isn't vital at this point, I just need to make it work. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What about a case `CASE WHEN Override IS NOT NULL THEN Override ELSE Value END`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with an inline `IIF`:

```
SELECT AVG (IIF(Override IS NOT NULL, Override, Value))
    OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Hourend) as Average
FROM Database.Table;
```

`IIF` is available for SQL Server 2012 and up.

Comment: I'm getting a "missing right parenthesis" error between Override and IS NOT NULL, but I have no clue what could be causing it. ><

Comment: It turns out that `Override` is a keyword in SQL Server. You need to wrap it insider square brackets: `IIF([Override] IS NOT NULL...`

Comment: Override isn't the actual name of the column; the actual name is OVERRIDE_XXX_XXX and the Value column is XXX_XXX (where Xs are identifying letters). Would this still cause an issue?

Comment: Runs fine on my computer. You can try boxing the column names in square brackets.

Comment: Tried it, now getting a "missing expression" error. Must be something I'm missing, maybe about how the database is set up? So frustrating...

Comment: Post your full query here. No one can help you troubleshoot it without seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

I would think this should work:

```
SELECT AVG (CASE WHEN Override IS NOT NULL THEN Override ELSE Value END)
OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Hourend) as Average
FROM Database.Table;
```

Comment: When tried this way I get an error that the Override after WHEN is an invalid identifier. This is odd as I can just go: select Override from database.table and it pulls it just fine.

Comment: you had an extra `(` in the original code you posted, and I copy/pasted yours :P

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (Value int, Override int , ID int, Hourend varchar(10) )


INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES (19,Null,1,'6:00')
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES(23,Null,1,'4:00')
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES(45,18 ,1,'6:00')
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES(66,Null,2,'6:00')
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES (68,Null,2,'5:00')
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES(72,Null,1,'5:00')
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES(81,45 ,1,'5:00')

SELECT  ID,Hourend  ,AVG(COALESCE(CAST(Override as decimal) ,CAST(VAlue as decimal)))
FROM #Temp
GROUP BY ID,Hourend
```

This should do the trick, COALESCE selects Override if it's not null,else it will select Value.

Comment: What happened to value here?  You need to case it out per the OPs requirements.

Comment: I'm hesitant to use Tables, mainly because I'm new to SQL Dev and have no clue where created table data is stored.  If it's in the database I'm not allowed to do it, as editing the database is never allowed (manually).

Comment: This is a temporarty table, it last as long as the session last. I made it just for the purpose of giving you an example. You can change the #Temp with your table name.